# How to create Map of tuples in ReasonML?

Tags: dictionary, tuples, reason

I'm very new to Reason. I have a tuple containing two strings and want to make a `Map` where the keys are of that tuple type.

How should I go about doing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I declare a map type in Reason ML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48830710/how-do-i-declare-a-map-type-in-reason-ml)

Comment: The documentation page also shows an example of creating a map of tuples (OCaml syntax though :-) https://reasonml.github.io/api/Map.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Map.Make` is a functor, which means it expects a module as its argument, not a type. The module argument must conform to the [`OrderedType`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.OrderedType.html) signature:

```
module type OrderedType = {
  type t
  let compare : (t, t) => int
}
```

In your case that would be something like:

```
module TuplesMap = Map.Make({
  type t = (string, string)
  let compare = (a, b) => ...
});
```

Then all you need to do is to implement the `compare` function.